# Can we query records in org immediate after deploy?

Tags: soql

I deployed few custom fields to production. Now I'm trying to fetch records based on those fields. Those fields are showing in Object fields, But developer console not querying. Will it take time or what could be the reason?

Comment: Based on my experience, after you deployed your field to production successfully, You can use it immediately to make a query. Do you encounter an error during querying ? Or maybe there is no record inserted on those field therefore there are no result when you run your query.

Comment: Is there any records available for the custom field you inserted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the fields are deployed successfully for the respective object. The most common reason for the field visibility issue in developer console is profile visibility. Please check you have the read permission for the new fields in your Profile.